# Long de longitud infinita

Tags: java

Buenas. Tengo una pregunta muy simple para ustedes. Me he informado y he visto que los datos tipo long de java solo llegan a 2^64. Hay algún modo, ya sea cambiando el tipo de dato o cualquier cosa, de lograr que los números puedan ser mayores?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a usar `BigInteger`. No tiene un límite teóricamente, sino que se adapta a la cantidad de memoria disponible.

Comment: También funciona cambiando de `long` a `double`, pero `BigInteger` supera el valor máximo de `double`.

Comment: Me podrías decir cómo se usa BigInteger? Se usa sustituyendo long directamente, o hay que importar utilidades?